# Formata data ISO (yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ) para ser apresentado no INPUT (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm)

Tags: html, data, angular

O servidor me entrega a data no formato ISO (yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ). Como faço para essa data ser apresentado no input com formato dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm?

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="tarefa.createdAt" />
```

Estou usando o angularJS v1.6.

Comment: a solução que encontrei foi instanciar um objeto Date(), passando como parâmetro a minha data no formato ISO. Então o meu tarefa.createdAt recebeu essa data.

Answer (score 0):

Quando passei por isso encontrei a recomendação de usar o **angular-datetime**

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" date='dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm' ng-model="tarefa.createdAt" />
```

https://github.com/eight04/angular-datetime